# iOS - Renewable In-App Purchases in an app that supports multiple user accounts on one device

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

### Background

My iOS app supports multiple user accounts, but the user can only be logged into one account at a time. The app also offers a subscription service ("credits" in the form of a renewable In-App Purchase).

I'm having trouble keeping the in-app subscriptions separated to the specific user account that bought them. If a user buys credits on Account One and then signs out, and another user signs into Account Two (on the same device), the `SKPaymentQueue` still proceeds with the renewal process for the purchases from Account One (and, consequently, triggers the logic that unlocks those credits).

### Question

What is the correct method of handling renewable in-app purchases for an app that supports multiple accounts? Is there any way to keep purchases from "overflowing" into other accounts on the same device? What else should be kept in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you're trying to do isn't possible. In-app purchases are tied to the Apple ID that purchased them. That means that if the user is logged into an Apple ID that has purchased the subscription, you are always going to be told it is available. A single user can't purchase the same subscription multiple times. The only way would be to force an Apple ID change when they change users in your app, which I'm almost certain you can't do.

Comment: I see. So you're saying it's impossible. Is there a way, perhaps, to _ignore_ the transaction based on certain conditions - or something like that?

Comment: You could try tracking by transaction id and storing it somewhere in your app, but you would need to persist it in iCloud or something so that you could use it if the user has multiple devices. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but it might be easier to use consumable purchases instead of a subscription.

Comment: Thanks for your help. We decided to do away with the multiple account "feature" - it was just making things too difficult within a subscription service.